# django populate a ModelMultipleChoiceField with date__year

Tags: django, forms, python-2.7

I would like to populate a ModelMultipleChoiceField with only the year, but i can't seem to find the right way of doing it!

For right now here is what i've got!

```
class DataForm(forms.Form):
    years = Servizi.objects.all().dates('data','year')
    year = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=years)
```

If i can explain better i would like it to be:

```
_______
2010
_______
2011 etc...
```

instead of

```
_______
2010-01-01
_________
2011-01-01 etc..
```

Is there an easy way??

Comment: Sounds like you've got the wrong data in the Servizi model to begin with: you seem to be storing dates, rather than years as integers.

Comment: Yes in my model I do store dates:
data = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date())
So there is no way to get just the year from here? I need to conver the date to integer elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I know its a bit hardcoded, but for right now its the only way i can find to populate the form!

```
class DataForm(forms.Form):

      years = Servizi.objects.all().dates('data','year')

      asd = []
      for year in years:
          asd.append((year.year,year.year))


      year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=asd)
```

Hope somebody will find it helpfull!